# Removing an objectID of an object in an array with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following in my clan scheme

```
var ClanScheme = new mongoose.Schema
({
    name: {type: String, unique: true},
    members: 
    [
      {
        user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User', unique: true},
        wins: {type: Number, default: 0},
        losses: {type: Number, default: 0}
      }
    ],
```

How do I remove a user from the clan? I've tried a few methods this looking like the least code:

```
clan.members.remove({'user':userObj._id});
clan.save(function(err)
```

It seems to run, but the user sticks in the document..

Clan

```
{ _id: 55e5e8d017e055495dcc3643,
  name: 'DBz',
  __v: 9,
  rating: 1000,
  losses: 0,
  wins: 0,
  rank: 0,
  members: 
   [ { user: [Object], 
       _id: 55e5e8d017e055495dcc3644,
       losses: 0,
       wins: 0 },
     { user: [Object],
       _id: 55e5eb0f17e055495dcc3645, //<< 55e4ac0340f964d52f8e7fb7
       losses: 0,
       wins: 0 } ] }
```

User

```
{ _id: 55e4ac0340f964d52f8e7fb7,
  facebookid: '999',
  name: 'Joe Blogs',
  __v: 0,
  lastDevice: { device: 'Desktop', id: 'adsbr2fjui33emk9p6gtnfrulv' },
  multiplayer: 
   { clanid: 55e5e8d017e055495dcc3643,
     powers: [],
     world_commander: 0,
     losses: 0,
     wins: 0,
     clanname: 'DBz',
     rating: 1000,
     rank: 0,
     username: 'Joe' },
  saveDataSeed: 40wq211,
  saveData: 'yuV2hVJA00zYGm'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter function and save.

```
clan.members = clan.members.filter(function(member){
  return String(member.user._id) !== String(userObj._id);
});

clan.markModified('members');
clan.save(function(err)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the user still sticks in the clan.

Comment: No error at all, it runs and say it's done but it doesn't really delete.

Comment: Post the result of `console.log(clan)` and `console.log(userObj)`

Comment: I've edited my answer as well, please add the markModified call

Comment: Oh, I see, that's because member.user is an object. In your console output, I cant see inside of it as its masked as [Object], but what you essentially want is to compare the _id's. I'm guessing it should be String(member.user._id). You'll still want the mark modified call. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you!! You've saved me hours of frustration!